# Removing cron jobs added by whenever gem when i move my application to a different server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

Suppose I have my rails application running on server A. I have also started some cron jobs added using the whenever gem. 
 
 Now if I want to shift my application to server B, is there a way to automatically stop (or remove) the cron jobs running on server A and start them on server B.

Comment: Do you shift servers often. How is the shifting done? Do you use capistrano?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. But if there is a way to solve the problem using capistrano, do tell me.

Comment: And ya we do shift our servers often. Every 3 months or so.

Comment: If you want automatic stopping cronjob, wouldn't it only makes sense if you have some automatic procedure to shift server? Otherwise how would the system know you have shifted.

Comment: Actually the application on server a wont be stopped. Both servers will still be running.
But users can only access the server b.

Comment: Actually the application on server a wont be stopped. Both servers will still be running.
But users can only access the server b.

So its kinda like maintenance. I redirect traffic to server b and do some changes in server a. When i redirect traffic the cron jobs should be stopped on server a and started on server b, as users will now access server b.

So I want to stop the cron job on one server and start it on another.